# How to prevent autoplay in iframe in ionic-v1?

Tags: html, ionic-framework, iframe

I want to play some videos in my ionic app but I cannot disable the autoplay with iframe. I have seen many solutions that suggest to use the `<video>` tag instead.

The code:

```
<iframe scrolling="yes" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="http://someurl?rel=0&autosize=true"  allowfullsceen></iframe>
```

My question is how to disable the autoplay in an iframe? Is it possible **without** using the video tag?

Comment: Even i faced the same issue. but there is no option to stop auto-play in iframe. it will be better if you use video tag. it is more efficient and you will have more control on video..

Comment: Thank you @rashmiranjan.